# Recommended way to style rectangles in drawings

Tags: graphics, drawing

With the drawing pallette I can create free-form graphics, but the built-in styling options only go so far.

Obviously I can create an image somewhere else and then paste it into graphics box, but that is kind of an ad-hoc solution.

Is there a recommended way to create complex styles for objects in the graphics box? By a "complex style" I will give two examples:

(1) Radial fills. A colored background on a rectangle that becomes more intense as it gets towards the edge of the rectangle.

(2) Double line strokes. Sometimes you want a double line instead of single-line stroke (for example to draw a road) and you need to control the distance between the two lines as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a satisfactory approach, but such a "Monte Carlo" variant:

```
 Graphics[Map[{Hue[(#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2)/2], 
    Point[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}]} &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100000, 2}]]]
```

giving

[image]

Here the parameters `{-1,1}` of the RandomReal fix the rectangle boundaries.

Have fun!

Comment: I know how to create radial gradients, that is not the question. The question is how to style *free form graphic objects in a graphics box* using, for example, a radial gradient. Basically, you do you style or modify the objects in a graphics box.